# Can't use .NET Core 5.0 application with Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.7.5

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, preview

A week ago I wanted to use .NET Core 5.0. I have installed it on my PC:

[image]

I used dotnet commands to create some applications. It worked well. I can even launch every application I have created with .NET Core 5.0.
Problems start when I create .NET Core Application with Visual Studio.

[image]

The solution explorer is full of warning signs:

[image]

`ConsoleApp1.csproj` file shows me that I use .NET Core 5.0 version as it should be:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

I didn't change the applications yet. `Program.cs:`

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

I decided that I should choose the `Target Framework` for my application. I went to the project settings and saw that my taget framework wasn't selected. I wanted to choose one but there is only `.NET Framework` target frameworks:

[image]

I tried to watch answers on the enternet. That is why I checked `Use previews of the .NET Core SDK (requires restart)` on:

[image]

It still doesn't work. It doesn't work with old or new projects. Maybe there is no chance to Debug `.NET Core 5.0` with Visual Studio now?

Comment: try `<TargetFramework>net5</TargetFramework>` ?

Comment: @MarcGravell `.net5.0` is the correct framework moniker, according to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#supported-target-frameworks)

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using? Using a preview SDK requires usage of Visual Studio Preview

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Visual Studio 2019 showing yellow exclamation for .NET 5 Preview 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63855684/visual-studio-2019-showing-yellow-exclamation-for-net-5-preview-8)

Comment: I use Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.7.5

Comment: Maybe the problem is I use the non-preview version of Visual Studio. Is there any way to download preview features in the Visual Studio Community?

Comment: @PavlentyCox No, you need to install the Preview version of VS separately. As far as I recall, it can live side-by-side with a non-Preview version with no issues, but it's been a while since I tried.

Comment: @PavlentyCox,I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use .NET Core 5.0 you should download the `preview version` of the visual studio separately (from here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/).
If you have already installed .NET Core 5.0 SDK and don't know how to switch back version of the .NET Core in your project to an earlier one, then write netcoreapp3.1 (maybe another version) instead of net5.0 in your `.csproj` file. For example my `ConsoleApp1.csproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Thanks to @Ian Kemp